# Given any non-real, complex number with positive real part, must some power of it has negative real part?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, trigonometry

Let $z\in \mathbb C$ such that $Re (z) >0 $ and $Im(z)\ne 0$. Then must there exist  integer $n>1$ such that $Re (z^n) <0$ ?

Equivalently, given $\theta \in [0, 2\pi)$ such that $\cos \theta >0$ and $\sin \theta \ne 0$ , must there exist $n>1$ integer such that $\cos (n\theta) <0$ ?

Comment: No, take $z=1$. Then no power of it has negative real part.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde : Sorry ... I forgot to add "non-real" ...

Comment: if $\theta<\pi/2$ then for sure we have $n$ such that $n\theta>\pi/2$ and hence $\cos n\theta$ is negative. The same is true if $\theta$ in the fourth quadrant

Comment: It suffices to consider $z$ with $|z|=1$ (aka "phasors"). In this case, the cyclic subgroup generated by $z$ is either a group of roots of unity or it is dense in the unit circle.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it's true.

Without loss of generality, we focus on $z$ with $|z| = 1$, and write $z = \cos(\theta) + i \sin(\theta)$, with $\theta \in (0, \frac\pi2) \cup (
\frac{3\pi}{2}, 2\pi)$ (since you're excluding real $z$, and only allowing $z$ with positive real part). Recall that by De Moivre, we have $z^k = \cos(k \theta) + i \sin(k \theta)$.

Note that the complex conjugate $\bar{z}$ has the same real part as $z$, and the same goes for $\bar{z}^n = \overline{z^n}$. For this reason, $z$ has some power with negative real part if and only if $\bar{z}$ does. Thus, we may further suppose that $\theta \in (0, \frac\pi2)$.

The basic idea is that $\theta$ must be between two angles of the form $\frac\pi n$ and $\frac{\pi}{n+1}$ for large enough $n$, and these are (relatively) easily shown to have a common multiple in the 2nd quadrant, hence some multiple of $\theta$ is there too.

Because $\theta \in (0, \frac\pi2)$, there exists some $n$ so that $\frac{\pi}{n+1} \le \theta < \frac{\pi}{n}$ (this is equivalent to an $n$ such that $n < \frac{\pi}{\theta} \le n + 1$), where $n > 2$.

Consequently, $\frac{n}{n+1}\pi \le n \theta < \pi$, where 
$$\frac{n}{n+1}\pi = (1 - \frac{1}{n+1})\pi > (1 - \frac{1}{n})\pi > \frac\pi2$$ 
since $n > 2$.

Thus, $\frac{\pi}{2} < n\theta < \pi$, hence $\cos(n\theta)$, the real part of $z^n$, is negative.

Comment: If you're going to just go ahead and assume that "without loss of generality", then you might as well go ahead and also assume $\theta = \pi/2$ "without loss of generality"... there's only so much to the problem...

Comment: @Mehrdad We can be more careful there, if you'd like. Pick any old $w \in \Bbb C$, and let $z = \frac{w}{|w|}$, where $|z| = 1$. Then, writing $w = |w|z$, we see that $w^k = \big(|w|z\big)^k = |w|^kz^k$. Since $|w|^k$ is real, we have that $\operatorname{Re}(w) = |w|^k \operatorname{Re}(z)$; one is negative if and only if the other is (hence, one has a power with negative real part if and only if the other does). But, the OP already (re)cast the problem purely in terms of trigonometry, realizing that scaling wouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 10):

If you think in terms of Eulers formula and powers as rotation, then the answer is obviously yes. For some rotation, the complex number will end up in the 2nd or 3rd Quadrant.

Comment: Don't say "obviously". Explain the intuition that is so clear in your mind. This is indeed the right way to think about the problem, but you have no way of knowing that OP shares this mental model with you.

Comment: @MichaelChirico Ok. I but how do I even explain it without any diagram

Comment: who said you can't use a diagram?

Answer (score 3):

You are sure to have $0<x/|z|<1$.  Calculate $\theta=\cos^{-1}(x/|z|)$ which will be greater than zero, then define $n$ as the largest whole number for which $n\theta \le \pi/2$.  What is $z^{n+1}?$